# Asking for an easy redirect script

Tags: redirect

i  don't know how to make a script that will redirect me from:

http://steamcommunity.com/market/* (Any link that contains steamcommunity market.)
to
https://steamcommunity.com/market/*

Http to Https.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.htaccess` file and upload into the Folder http://steamcommunity.com/market/

.htaccess content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this code at the top of the page you want to redirect before any other code including the head

```
<?php
  header('Location: http://yourdomain.com/your-new-page/', true, 301);
  exit();
?>
```